# How to create dummy records based on sample from dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a 40 record df with roughly 100 columns.

example:

df

```
id   email       phone    first_name ......
1    a@a.com     123       adam
2    b@b.com     456       bob
```

Is there any way I can take a sample of each column and have python develop sample data based on the types of data in the columns?

So the code auto generates fake id, email, and phone numbers. ideally, I can set the number of fake records I needed created, for example 2million rows are needed and I can appended the word `fake` into one of the columns like `first_name`.

new df

```
id   email       phone    first_name ......
1    a@a.com     123       adam
2    b@b.com     456       bob
3    c@c.com     789       fake_carly
4    c@c.com     789       fake_david
```

Comment: Although it does not use python to develop sample data, I have found this site to be a great resource for generating test data: https://www.mockaroo.com/

Comment: I have not used this before but `faker` seems to be a highly used and well received python library.  Take a look: https://github.com/joke2k/faker

Comment: @user9074332 I tried mockaroo, however I am limited to only a 1000 rows, but it was what I am looking for. Checking out faker thank you .

Comment: @user9074332 faker is excellent, I will accept as my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python `faker` library seems to be well received for the type of thing you are doing.

More information can be found here:
[github.com/joke2k/faker](https://github.com/joke2k/faker)